# Can I (and if I can, how do I) enforce a specific string encoding for running lua scripts with jedis?

Tags: java, lua, redis, jedis

I suspect that jedis decodes my string to the wrong byte set before calling my lua script. Can I configure which string encoding/decoding algorithm or function is used?

***Context***

I'm calling a lua script from jedis, somewhat like so:

```
evalResponse = jedis.eval(aLuaScriptString, 1, someKey, Double.toString(aDouble), new String(aByteArray, ‘UTF-8’), Integer.toString(anInteger));
```

where the lua script performs a zadd:

```
redis.call('zadd', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
```

When I retrieve the byteArray from redis, it contains a different set of bytes than the ones I sent in.

Since the string representations of the retrieved bytes, and the bytes I'm sending in are identical, I strongly suspect that somewhere along the jedis/lua invocation path my string is decoded to bytes differently than how I encoded it.

Comment: Have you tried `BinaryJedis`? You can pass in a `byte[]` and do the string to bytes encoding yourself.

Comment: @mp911de BinaryJedis seems limited to a 1:1 relationship between keys and script argument byte arrays. I've been assuming that means it will only accept one argument per key - maybe i'm wrong? is there a documented way to construct the argument byte array to contain more than one argument?

Comment: Actually, the eval method concatenates the key and the param arrays to pass only one, two-dimensional byte array down to the transport. So the number of keys and number of additional args do not correlate. Similar implementation in lettuce.

Comment: @mp911de sure, that's true - still sucks that ther's a 1 argument per key limit

Comment: note that the arg/key limit is not present after upgrading from jedis 2.1 to 2.7